# Connecting an external HDD in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, ext4

I have a double boot Linux/Windows 8.1 laptop and connect an external HDD formatted in ext4 to it.

It works fine with Linux and I do not intend to use it with Windows. I am wary that when I boot Windows, it might try to mount it, and not being able, might try to 'repair' it.

Could this happen? That is, could Windows damage an ext4 formatted external HDD?

Comment: Preventing good old Windows from auto-mounting a volume may be a question best asked on a Win forum.

Comment: It's just not a concrete volume or Windows installation. It's about marking  ext4 volumes in general for not being mounted by Windows (or messed with). If that happens, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Windows shouldn't do anything unless you respond yes to a query to repair or format a volume when it mounts.

But, as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/959522/prevent-windows-10-from-formatting-ext4-partition-on-pendrive) link says, Win 10 behaviour has changed from ignoring ext4 FS to asking to modify them. Who knows what Microsoft will do next.

There are workarounds in the link, loop mounting the volume or using UDF, but they don't really address your problem at core.

Windows Server can have automount disabled in the registry but I've just checked my Win10 registry keys and can find no equivalent on a desktop install. Only seem to be mount options for ISO/VHD/Sharepoint.